# tnsconnect shows operation timeout

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Here is my use case:

> 1. We are using virtual machine. Couple of days ago I have created new Oracle database. I cloned this machine and it got different IP address.
> 2. Today I wanted to connect to the database using SQLPlus but I go connection timeout. I have tried tnsping command and here is the output of that command:
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>tnsping clm
>
> TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-JAN-2
> 014 08:36:31
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
> C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
>
> Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
> Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTO
> COL=TCP)(HOST=9.142.60.187)(PORT=1521)))
> TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out

What is weird, that the current database address is different than 9.142.60.187. sqlnet.ora also does not contain any interesting data:

> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
>
> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
> ?
> ADR_BASE = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log

How can I make my connection to sqlplus available?
What is interesting, I am able to connect to the database using jdbc driver and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sqlnet.ora is configured to first try to use TNSNAMES (tnsnames.ora in your TNS_ADMIN directed folder as defined in registry, environment variable or taken from default location) to resolve `clm` to a path through your network mapping SQL*Net to TCP/IP and possibly others.

From your tnsping that seems not to resolve. Therefore, SQL*Net tries the second one: EZCONNECT. [See Oracle docs on that one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm).

Probably you are using somewhere an EZCONNECT connection string like user/pwd@//9.142.60.187 without service name and port. Or my knowledge of EZCONNECT is too simple; somehow it seems to translate `clm` into `//9.142.60.187`. **That might be explained by the answer to the following question: Do you have a hostname `clm` in DNS or hosts file mapping to 9.142.60.187?**

I do not recommend using EZCONNECT, I always like to have tnsnames.ora hard coded, specifying everything needed. EZCONNECT can work nonetheless.

**Can you include IP address of clone in your sample?**

**Can you include outcome of `ping clm` and `nslookup clm` in your sample?**

Comment: OK. It seems that I am really lammer in Oracle. I thought that the parameter for `tnsping` should be database name, not host name. Simply I was using wrong command. I will create separate post with my real issue. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi, the parameter for tnsping is neither database name nor host name. It is a so-called "service name". The service name is resolved through the list of mechanisms specified. Compare it to the contents of resolv.conf on UNIX. One possible service name resolution is host name (EZCONNECT), another one is a look up in tnsnames.ora and there are others available too.

Comment: I do not agree with the statement that EZCONNECT is too hard to use.  I hate maintaining TNSNAMES.ORA files particularly in a multiple workstation environment.  Hosts and service names do not seem to change willy-nilly (unpredictably) so the construct
TNSPING host.domain:1521/SERVICE_NAME is more stable.
That being said, be very sure that EZCONNECT is not first in your SQLNET.ORA 
setting  >>> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)  not
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (EZCONNECT,TNSNAMES) because the latter will  return random IP that do not exist when you enter TNSPING SOME_DB_ALIAS

Answer (score 0):

Change the ip address in `(HOST=9.142.60.187)` to the current ip address of server. May be in the JDBC driver you are using host name instead of ip address and that's why it is working. You can also try giving host name in `(HOST=9.142.60.187)`, e.g if host name is ora_server then change it to `(HOST=ora_server)`

Comment: where I should change this value?

Comment: Get the hostname or ipaddress of your Oracle server and update it in the tnsnames.ora file. There you have `(HOST=9.142.60.187)`, change it to `(HOST=<new ip address>)` or `(HOST=<new hostname>)`. If this doesn't work then follow suggestions from Alex and Guido.

Answer (score 0):

Since `tnsping clm` is using EZConnect, your `tnsnames.ora` does not have an connection alias called `CLM`, but `clm` is being resolved as a host name to `9.142.60.187`. It's using port 1521 by default as it has no instructions to use a specific port. The connection to that address, or at least that port, is then timing out - it might not exist, it might route somewhere unreachable, or it might be blocked by a firewall.

`ping clm` should show the same address, and will probably also time out. That host may exist in your `hosts` file, or is being resolved by DNS, possible with a default domain appended, which `ping` would also show. If it is the name of your old server, you might need to update your `hosts` file, which might magically make it start working.

If your database is actually called `CLM` then you can create an entry in your `tnsnames.ora` that points to the correct IP address for your listener, which your JDBC connection is already using. Or you can use the EZConnect format as your connect string; something like `sqlplus user/password@//<your IP>:1521/<your service name>`. You can use `lsnrctl services` to check the IP address, port and service name if you aren't sure.

If you're on the same host as the database then you don't need to do either; presumably you're currently trying `sqlplus user/password@clm`, but if `ORACLE_SID` is set you can just do `sqlplus user/password` and it will not trouble the listener.